# Bash Script to chreck dir size and delete based on days old

Tags: bash

I am busy writing a shell script; and am stuck. I am trying to check a directory for a specific size breach; when it gets there; I want to delete files in said directory; based on +mtime.
That being said; I am quite new to bash and am stuck in the arithmetic section. Here's the code:
    #!/bin/bash

```
# Usage: cleanup_old_logs &lt;folder&gt; &lt;days&gt;
# Removes all log files in the directory older than a certain number of days

ALERT=90
FOLDER=~ NAME_TO_FOLDER_T)_MONITOR - removed for example
SIZE=$(df -k $FOLDER | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')
N_DAYS=2

# check if the available space is smaller than < 90%
if (($SIZE -gt $ALERT)); then
# find all files under $FOLDER and delete them
echo "Deleting files in $FOLDER older than $N_DAYS days"
# Remove
find $FOLDER/* -maxdepth 1 -mtime +$N_DAYS  -type f|wc -l ## -exec rm -rf {} \;
fi
```

This is my error:

```
line 13: ((: 86% -gt 90%: division by 0 (error token is "90%")
```

Comment: I just realized that my question is incomplete. Can someone maybe briefly explain to me what I am doing wrong in my arithmetic; and maybe point me in the right direction?

Comment: I recommend using Powershell when things get too complicated in batch files. It requires some learning time, but it is much more powerful then batch files.

Comment: Use sed to remove the trailing % in SIZE. But be aware that it’s not tracking folder size, but usage in percentage of a specific mount. You should use du to find directory size.

Comment: Also, your script isn’t in sync with the error you posted, ALERT is set to 90 in the script, shows 90% in the error.

Comment: `I am trying to check a directory for a specific size breach` For this you would have to check the directory size using `du` not the whole mount point `df`

Comment: I got it to work! Just had to use sed:

SIZE=$(df -H $FOLDER |tail -n1| awk '{print $4}'|sed 's|%||g')

Comment: Thanks to all. I am actually checking the mount size; as Timr pointed out...

Answer (score 0):

`df` is used to check file systems. Man page:

> df displays the amount of disk space available on the file system containing each file name argument.

You need `du` instead

`du -s /home/lohit/bin | cut -f1`

Result

`43567213`